# Dynamic labels in c# windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms, updown

So, I'm trying to get a label to reflect the current settings of whatever action is taking place.

```
this.SettingXLbl.Text = "The current value-set is " + SettingUpDown.Value;
```

I modified the auto-generated code to attempt to display the current value in the SettingUpDown, but I'm only getting zeroes.

I traded `.Value` for `.Minimum` still to get a zero result. The minimum value for the up-down is greater than zero so I'm not sure what I need to do differently to get it to reflect the current value held in the up-down.

Is there some other property that I need to be changing rather than the text itself.

Comment: Where are you setting this value?

Comment: You need to run that code in the `ValueChanged` handler of `SettingUpDown`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thank you. That's exactly what the problem was. For some reason that wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.SettingXLbl.Text = "The current value-set is " + SettingUpDown.Value;
```

You changed that line in the designer's `InitializeComponent` method. That method is called only once, when the form is constructed. So it will always reflect the value of `SettingUpDown.Value` at that point in time, which probably was 0 at the time of the form's construction.

You have to explicitly update the label's text in some event. For example, the `NumericUpDown` control has a [`ValueChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged.aspx) in which you can change the label's text when the value has changed. Simply select the component in the designer, in the Properties window let it display the events, and double click the `ValueChanged` event. Visual Studio will insert a method stub and associate it with the event. You can fill this stub with any code you want to do your bidding. Something like this:

```
public void SettingUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArguments e)
{
    this.SettingXLbl.Text = "The current value-set is " + SettingUpDown.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! That's exactly what I needed to fix it. For some reason it didn't occur to me to change the label when looking at the Up-down event